# Alternative to tongue and groove adhesive for hardwood floor

Tags: hardwood

I'm installing an engineered hardwood product in my office, 5" Shaw Epic hardwood. It is tongue and groove, but not a click-lock type. For a floating installation, the tongues and grooves need to be glued together. There's a 20-second video of the installation at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zkn_qtL8snw.

I have a bit of a time crunch (I want the floor in before the carpet guys come in a few days) and I'm not sure I can get ahold of any proper tongue and groove adhesive in time. The folks at local hardware stores I've asked look at me funny and say they haven't seen non-click-lock hardwood in 5 or 10 years.

Can I use regular wood glue for this, instead of tongue and groove adhesive? If not, is there another easy-to-obtain alternative?

It will be installed on foam underlay over OSB over dimpled foundation membrane over concrete in my basement, if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a simple white wood glue. That should be no problem here. Do NOT use a polyurethane wood glue here like Gorilla glue, as that will expand out and cause a mess, as well as possibly push the boards apart.

If you are unsure if it will work, try some white wood glue on a test piece. It will dry within an hour.

Comment: Thanks. For anyone wondering how far a bottle glue goes, I used about 1000ml for 350 linear ft of seam.